# Heroku Node.js (express.js) App Works Locally but failed on heroku when using MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku

I have an node.js app based on express.js, it works fine on localhost, and it also can connect the Mlab database from localhost:

```
sheng@Takeshi:~/Work/smr_pjt_loct_dr$ NODE_ENV=production MONGODB_URI=mongodb://heroku_60bjp5jd:PASSWORD@ds115712.mlab.com:15712/heroku_60bjp5jd nodemon start
[nodemon] 1.11.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www start`
test:mongodb://heroku_60bjp5jd:PASSWORD@ds115712.mlab.com:15712/heroku_60bjp5jd
test the dbURI:mongodb://heroku_60bjp5jd:PASSWORD@ds115712.mlab.com:15712/heroku_60bjp5jd
Mongoose connected to mongodb://localhost/smr_pjt_loctog
Mongoose log disconnected
Db.prototype.authenticate method will no longer be available in the next major release 3.x as MongoDB 3.6 will only allow auth against users in the admin db and will no longer allow multiple credentials on a socket. Please authenticate using MongoClient.connect with auth credentials.
Mongoose connected to mongodb://heroku_60bjp5jd:PASSWORD@ds115712.mlab.com:15712/heroku_60bjp5jd
Succeeded connected to: mongodb://heroku_60bjp5jd:PASSWORD@ds115712.mlab.com:15712/heroku_60bjp5jd
```

But when I pushed to heroku, it failed, the error message is shown below:

```
2017-06-14T11:19:43.117450+00:00 app[web.1]: MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
```

It says that I have failed when connecting to the local server. However, I have set the heroku config var correctly, and as can be seen form below:

```
sheng@Takeshi:~/Work/smr_pjt_loct_dr$ heroku config
=== smr-pjt-loct-dr Config Vars
MONGODB_URI: mongodb://heroku_60bjp5jd:PASSWORD@ds115712.mlab.com:15712/heroku_60bjp5jd
NODE_ENV:    production
```

And as for MLAB database URI, I can get it using code below in the db.js file:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
console.log("test:" + process.env.MONGODB_URI);
dbURI = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
console.log('test the dbURI:' + dbURI);}
```

I guess the problem is about mongoose, but I have tried many ways, 
such as, upgrading and specifying the version of Node and NPM in package.json file, or installing the MongoDB driver.

But it cannot work, I have deleted the mongoose connection code below:

```
mongoose.connect(dbURI, function (err, res) {
  if (err) {
  console.log ('ERROR connecting to: ' + dbURI + '. ' + err);
  } else {
  console.log ('Succeeded connected to: ' + dbURI);
  }
});
```

And the error message is still the same:

```
2017-06-14T11:19:43.117450+00:00 app[web.1]: MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
```

And I actually set the Mlab database by using heroku addons correctly as can be seen from [image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyrTb.png):

Is there someone can help me? Thanks indeed !!!

## Update:

As for error message that I have found form heroku logs:

```
2017-06-14T16:21:49.064801+00:00 app[web.1]: MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
2017-06-14T16:21:49.064802+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Pool.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:328:35)
2017-06-14T16:21:49.064803+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
2017-06-14T16:21:49.064804+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Pool.emit (events.js:191:7)
2017-06-14T16:21:49.064805+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:280:12)
2017-06-14T16:21:49.064805+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
2017-06-14T16:21:49.064806+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
2017-06-14T16:21:49.064807+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection.emit (events.js:194:7)
2017-06-14T16:21:49.064808+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:177:49)
2017-06-14T16:21:49.064808+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
2017-06-14T16:21:49.064809+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
2017-06-14T16:21:49.064809+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
2017-06-14T16:21:49.064810+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitErrorNT (net.js:1279:8)
2017-06-14T16:21:49.064811+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
2017-06-14T16:21:49.064812+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

I haven't found anything which is related to the mongose, it seems that the mongodb-core should be responsible for the connection of database, however, I didn't use this npm_module at all.

I have tried to delete the whole node_module folder and use npm install to install them again, but still cannot work.

In addition, I have tried to get the netstat of my localhost:

```
sheng@Takeshi:~/Work/smr_pjt_loct_dr$ sudo netstat -atunlp | grep "27017"
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1034/mongod
```

## Solved:

Problem resolved, thanks for the help of @vsenko, hahaha!!!
I have another connection of local database, and I haven't noticed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, the error message that you receive does not contain the string that you write to console is case of connections failure:

`console.log ('ERROR connecting to: ' + dbURI + '. ' + err);`

So my best guess is that the error you receive originates from another attempt to connect to the same or another database.

Comment: yes, the mongoose.connect seems useless, it do not reveal any message in   the console.log(), but it actually work when I use localhost to access the Mlab database, it actually confused me. And I cannot find any other place in my code that can be used to connect database.

Comment: all the database connection code is in the db.js file.

Comment: But what about this line of your output: 'Mongoose connected to mongodb://localhost/smr_pjt_loctog'?

Comment: this line is about the database of user information (username, password,), and temporarily useless

Comment: According to your update, you have a local mongo running. Try to shut it down and run your app again locally.

Comment: After I shutdown the local mongo, I tried to run my app locally, but it failed, the error is the same: `MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect`

Comment: So there is definitely a place in your app where you connect to the local mongo service. Try searching your sources for a string 'smr_pjt_loctog'.

Comment: yes, I have found this code in my db.js:`var logDB = mongoose.createConnection(dbURIlog);`

Comment: Switch it to Heroku and that's it.

Comment: Oh, god, I remove this code, and it actually works on heroku, you saved my life, so  appreciate!!!

Comment: I'm glad! Could you please mark the answer as a correct one.